# dynamically/condionally choosing from pure python, numba.jit and numba.cuda.jit

Tags: python, performance, numba

what is the best way to have better, dynamic control on the decorators - choosing from `numba.cuda.jit`, `numba.jit` and none (pure python). [please note that a project can have 10s or 100s of functions, so this should be easy to apply to all the functions] 
here is an example from numba  website.

```
import numba as nb
import  numpy as np

# global control of this --> @nb.jit or @nb.cuda.jit  or none 
# some functions with @nb.jit or cuda.jit with kwargs like (nopython=True, **other_kwargs)
def sum2d(arr):
    M, N = arr.shape
    result = 0.0
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
            result += arr[i,j]
    return result


a = np.arange(81).reshape(9,9)

sum2d(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want something more sophisticated, but a relatively simple solution is redefining `jit` based on settings.  For example

```
def _noop_jit(f=None, *args, **kwargs):
    """ returns function unmodified, discarding decorator args"""
    if f is None:
        return lambda x: x
    return f

# some config flag
if settings.PURE_PYTHON_MODE:
    jit = _noop_jit
else: # etc
    from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def f(a):
    return a + 1
```